# the form object placed in ModelMap seems cleared somewhere when some action is invoked

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a Controller, that deals with two forms.

in initialize Form Method i set all the stuff requird to render the screen. and put the form object to the model map.

on the render phase the rendering is done successfuly. but when submit is done and the @ActionMapping is invoked.

I got the exception with.

```
org.springframework.web.portlet.handler.PortletSessionRequiredException: Session attribute 'someForm' required - not found in session
        at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$PortletHandlerMethodInvoker.raiseSessionRequiredException(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:554)
        at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveModelAttribute(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:758)
        at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:356)
        at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:171)
        at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:360)
        at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.doHandle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:347)
        at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handleAction(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:281)
        at org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet.doActionService(DispatcherPortlet.java:641)
        at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.processRequest(FrameworkPortlet.java:519)
        at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.processAction(FrameworkPortlet.java:460)
        at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:70)
        at com.nomadsoft.cortex.infrastructure.spring.security.SecurityContextAuthenticatedPortletFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextAuthenticatedPortletFilter.java:99)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor554.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

**If i Place the Object into HTTP session that i obtain from Request object and manipulate through the process every thing Goes fine**

I do;t know what is going wrong when i work with model map.

in the rest of the application there are more other controllers those are working fine.

Any Clue will be highly appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your forms need the 'someForm' attributs (`Session attribute 'someForm' required`).
This attribut must be called in your page.

Comment: Hi i have on class level defined @SessionAttributes(value = {"someForm", "someForm2"}) and at the method level i have defined the method as @ActionMapping(params = "actionDoMyStuff") public void DoActiveStuff(@ModelAttribute("someForm") MyForm myForm, @ModelAttribute("myForm2") MyForm2 myForm2, BindingResult errors, ActionRequest request, ModelMap model, ActionResponse response)